# sql search query on radio buttons using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

in my sidebar there are radio buttons and want to put a search query like if radio button `new` is selected then `select * from products` and if `old` selected then `select * from posts`. In `view/element/sidebar.ctp` which contains:

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    NEW
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    USED
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check submitted value in your controller.

```
$this->request->data['optionsRadios'];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,I am new to Cakephp, need your more help, I want to call/echo a controller's action variable from my sidebars(which is located in view/element) buttons? please help me.

Comment: The above code is written in view/element/sidebar.ctp and when a sidebar button or radio button is select I want to show some products results in body.

Comment: cakephp pass variable from controller to view by call $this->set('varNameToUseInView', $varNameInController);